# How can i install figlet and toilet on Centos6

Tags: installation, centos, yum

I have yum and rpm, and I really only how to install packages using these commands. When I tried to yum install figlet on a new CentOS6 virtual machine it couldn't find it in the mirrors list. I tried to localinstall a figlet package but it wasnt signed and yum wouldnt install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[here](http://pkgs.repoforge.org/figlet/) you can download the figlet packge and install it with rpm -U, or do yum --nogpgcheck packgename .

as a general recommendation, i am encourge you to add the [RpmForge](http://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories/RPMForge) repos to you centos installation, since it includes a lot of programs.

see this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26011/how-do-you-add-a-package-or-a-mirror-if-the-rpm-youre-looking-for-isnt-avail).

Comment: haha thats an answer to my question!